# How found max data vote from docs in collection and after add a new collection for each win found with flutter and firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to count votes of the day and create a new collection for each win vote of each days. The goal is to display a list of win vote.

To do this I try to configure firestore like this:

```
 Collection    document          data

    ------------current working part--------------

    2020-08-01      user1       votes:1, data_user1
                    user4       votes:4, data_user4
                    user8       votes:2, data_user8

    2020-08-02      user11      votes:3, data_user11
                    user12      votes:2, data_user12
                    user17      votes:1, data_user17

    2020-08-03      user21      votes:3, data_user21
                    user23      votes:2, data_user23

---------------------part I try to add--------------

   list_of_win       user4       data_user4
                     user11      data_user11
                     user21      data_user21

------------------------------------------------------
```

First I search to found winner of one day collection.

For example:

```
2020-08-01      user1       votes:1, data_user1
                user4       votes:4, data_user4
                user8       votes:2, data_user8
```

the winner is `user4`.

After win I need to upgrade the `list_of_win` collection with `user4` as doc and `data_user4` as data.

I need to do this for each day collection.

My first and ugly working idea is to create a function to read just the previous day from today and read data from collection to determine a winner and create a new `list_of_win` but if I have no user's one day who open app to launch the calcul function who fetch the daily winner, this day will be a day with no winner...

Other idea, but I don't know how to do, is to load all collections in a json file and create a `forEach` loop to scan all data by groups of days and for each days update list_of_win.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not create a [cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) for that? Since this is clearly a automatic process you could take this processing away from your app and run it on the server side, you could [schedule it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run everyday at midnight to calculate the last day winner and store it in your `list_of_win`. You could even push notifications to users saying who is the winner with Cloud Functions, do you think this might be doable in your use case?

Comment: I'm noob about firebase and cloud, I just start to understand firestore but for this projet I see the limit. Certainly your solution seems better, but I start to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using Firebase you could create a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) for that, with that you can take this automatic process out of your app and run it on a daily schedule on the server side, [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) shows you how to do that.

This will eliminate the problem of a user having to be active to trigger the function. Also, you can create notifications to let your users know who is the winner of each day, [here](https://engineering.monstar-lab.com/2021/02/09/Use-Firebase-Cloudfunctions-To-Send-Push-Notifications#:%7E:text=When%20the%20Cloud%20functions%20are,triggered%20by%20the%20data%20listener.) is a tutorial for that as well.

Since you are not familiar with Cloud Functions I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation and try it out, since it's quite simple to use, as this would be the most correct/efficient way to achieve what you want, nevertheless here is an example of a cloud function that would calculate this for you:

```
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.calculateWinner = functions.pubsub.schedule('1 0 * * *').onRun((context) => {
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
    var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

    var newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    admin.firestore().collection(newdate).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        var leadingUser = null;
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            if(leadingUser == null){
                leadingUser = doc;
            }else if(leadingUser.data().votes < doc.data().votes){
                leadingUser = doc;
            }
        });
        //by this point leadingUser will be the winner and you can build the object to be added to list_of_win as required in here
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
});
```